# How to Git Rebase without overwriting local changes

Tags: git, github

I synced a tag called v1 down to my local machine from a remote github respository and pushed to a new branch called MyBranch. I then made a set of changes to MyBranch, committed them, and then synced to my remote repository.

I then wanted to refresh my local machine with the latest tag from the remote repository, so I tried to rebase MyBranch to V2 as follows:

```sh
git pull V2
git checkout MyBranch
git rebase -i V2
```

When I did this, I saw:

1. A set of CONFLICT messages
2. All changes from V2 were synced to my local machine, overwriting the changes I had made in MyBranch

I made no changes after this. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Which files were changed in your branch and which files were changed between v1 and v2?

Answer (score 0):

When you `pull`, you already *merge* the remote changes into your local branch (unless the config `pull.rebase=true` is in effect).

If there are conflicts, they will probably show up during the `pull` (IOW merge) step already. But it could very well be that the conflicts only show up during rebase, while the merge itself can be done automatically.

A conflict means that two branches changed the same lines in the same file or lines that are very close. You need to resolve those conflicts and then commit the result.